About Nextjs + tailwindcss + NextUI mobile end adaptation md: hidden does not work
I used nextjs14+typescript+tailwindcss to make a website https://www.all-free-novels.com, initially according to the web version to do, later want to optimize the time to do mobile end, when doing mobile end adaptation, I hope to achieve "block md: hidden" function, that is, a component, such as the navigation bar, when the mobile end is displayed as an icon, and when the md icon is hidden, displayed as a text version of the navigation bar, currently found that hidden md: block is working, but block md:hidden is not working
Tried a lot, it's weird
I am a novice at the front end, is there any god who can see what the problem is?
the code is like that
return (
    <Navbar className="px-0">
      <NavbarBrand>
        <Logo />
      </NavbarBrand>
      <NavbarContent className="gap-4" justify="center">
        <NavbarItem className="hidden md:block">
          <Link color="foreground" href={`/${locale}`}>
            {t('home')}
          </Link>
        </NavbarItem>
        <NavbarItem className="hidden md:block">
          <Link color="foreground" href={`/${locale}/ranking`}>
            {t('rank')}
          </Link>
        </NavbarItem>
        <NavbarItem className="hidden md:block">
          <Link color="foreground"  href={`/${locale}/category`}>
            {t('category')}
          </Link>
        </NavbarItem>
        <NavbarItem className="hidden md:block">
          <Link color="foreground" href={`/${locale}/search`}>
            {t('search')}
          </Link>
        </NavbarItem>
      </NavbarContent>
      <NavbarContent justify="end">
        <LocaleSwitcher />
        <ThemeSwitcher />
        <NavbarItem className="md:hidden">
          <Menu/>
        </NavbarItem>
      </NavbarContent>
    </Navbar>
  )

I try to use "md:hidden" or "block md:hidden" or use a div tag wrapped it, all of them are not working.
I hope when use "md:hidden" and when screen is middle or larger, then don't show the menu icon and NavbarItem
<NavbarItem className="md:hidden">
 <Menu/>
</NavbarItem>


Can i see inside your NavbarItem component that includes the whole function ?

Just the a dropdown component
      <Dropdown>
        <DropdownTrigger>
          <Button isIconOnly color="default" variant="flat" >
            <MenuIcon size={18}/>
          </Button>
        </DropdownTrigger>
        <DropdownMenu aria-label="Menu" onAction={(key) => navTo(key.toString())}>
          <DropdownItem key="home">{home}</DropdownItem>
          <DropdownItem key="ranking">{ranking}</DropdownItem>
          <DropdownItem key="category">{category}</DropdownItem>
        </DropdownMenu>
      </Dropdown>


are you trying to display the Hamburger icon on the Navbar only when on mobile and make it hidden on desktop? If so, add md:hidden class.
If not, it'll be more helpful if you can add a codesandbox of your code for better understanding.
